# I installed a jupyterhub on my remote server, but when I access it, it shows jupyter notebook, not jupyter lab

Tags: jupyterhub

I have added `c.Spawner.cmd = ['jupyter-labhub', '--notebook-dir', '/mnt/home']` in jupyter_config.py

I want this:

[image]

but it show me this：

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does your url end in `/tree`? if so, replace "tree" with lab, e.g. `/lab`

Also, make sure you have jupyterlab installed in the notebook user environment, and that it's compatible with the version of jupyter running on the notebook and on the hub.

If everything is set up with a recent version of jupyterhub/jupyterlab, the jupyterlab interface should be the defualt. There is away to configure the notebook interface to be the default, so make sure you *don't* have the following in your spec. From the [JupyterHub docs](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jupyterhub/customizing/user-environment.html#selecting-a-user-interface):

> If you install the `nbclassic` package, you can also default to the classic UI, running on the new server: This may be the best way to support users on both classic and new environments.
>
> ```yaml
> singleuser:
>   defaultUrl: /tree/
>   extraEnv:
>     JUPYTERHUB_SINGLEUSER_APP: "jupyter_server.serverapp.ServerApp"
> ```

Instead, you could set `defaultUrl: /lab/`, though this should be the default.

See the JupyterHub docs on [customizing the user interface](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jupyterhub/customizing/user-environment.html#selecting-a-user-interface) for more info.